# Knowledge Tab visibility on sandbox

Tags: community, knowledge

Is the Knowledge Tab available in a sandbox? I am trying to add the Article and Knowledge Tabs on to the App in sandbox but I couldn't find Knowledge Tab.

I have enabled Knowledge User and created Article Types. I have all permissions.

Comment: Do you have it on production ? I think it's part of the service cloud and needs to be enabled per org if it wasn't enabled on production when you did your sandbox create/refresh.

Comment: I'm testing it on sandbox directly.

Answer (score 1):

Is the tab visible to your profile?
For the article management tab you would need the "“Manage Articles" permission.